# Linkedin: android, Unable to get Profile Picture

Tags: android, image

I want to get the Profile image of Linkedin. I give  r_basicprofile permission, But no results.

My code is:

```
Person person = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(ProfileField.ID, ProfileField.FIRST_NAME,
                            ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.HEADLINE,
                            ProfileField.INDUSTRY, ProfileField.PICTURE_URL,
                            ProfileField.DATE_OF_BIRTH, ProfileField.LOCATION_NAME,
                            ProfileField.MAIN_ADDRESS, ProfileField.LOCATION_COUNTRY));
```

Answer (score -1):

yes you can, make a variable url, and url = new URL(person.getPicture_URL); then have BitmapFactory to decode the url.